# How do I get my userform check box to turn true when the selection is yellow?

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to get my check box on my userform to turn true when the cell next to the selected one is yellow.

I'd like to do basically the same thing, but it be the active cell and strikethrough.

```
If ActiveCell.Offset(-1).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0) Then
            
         Results.Sent.Value = True
            
            End If
```

And

```
If ActiveCell = Font.Strikethrough Then
            
            Confirmed.Value = False
            
            End If
```

Comment: `If ActiveCell.Font.Strikethrough Then`    See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.font.strikethrough

Answer (score 2):

Note there's a more concise way to do this:

```
With ActiveCell
    Results.Sent.Value = (.Offset(-1).Interior.Color = vbYellow) 
    Confirmed.Value = Not .Font.Strikethrough 'unchecked when font is struck out
End With
```